# 2D Java Array Values not correlated to my intention

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Fire {

    public static Integer seed;
    public static Integer width;
    public static Integer height;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Firebot <seed> <width> <height>");
            return;
        }
        try {
            width = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            height = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Firebot <seed> <width> <height>");
            return;
        }
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Integer day = 1;
        String wind = "none";
        double damage = 0.00;
        Integer pollution = 0;

        Integer seed = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Integer width = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        Integer height = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        int [][] SimulationArray = new int[width][height];
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                Integer DoubleHeight = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
                if (DoubleHeight == 10) {
                    SimulationArray[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (DoubleHeight > 2) {
                    SimulationArray[i][j] = DoubleHeight;
                }
                else {
                    SimulationArray[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
                    if (SimulationArray[i][j] == 0) {
                        System.out.print("  ");
                        }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(SimulationArray[i]));
                        System.out.print("  ");
                    }
                }
            System.out.println();
            }
        System.out.print("\n");

    }
}
```

I am trying to print a 2D array that is modelled based on random numbers and their values.

Currently my code prints below in the console.

```
[user@sahara ~]$ java Fire 4 5 4

[3, 8, 9, 3]  [3, 8, 9, 3]  [3, 8, 9, 3]  [3, 8, 9, 3]
[6, 4, 0, 9]  [6, 4, 0, 9]    [6, 4, 0, 9]
[5, 0, 3, 5]    [5, 0, 3, 5]  [5, 0, 3, 5]
[0, 8, 6, 0]  [0, 8, 6, 0]
[0, 8, 8, 6]  [0, 8, 8, 6]  [0, 8, 8, 6]
```

In reality what I want to print is something like this

```
[user@sahara ~]$ java Fire 4 5 4

4 5 2 3 4
2 3 4 4 5
4 5 2 3 4
2 3 4 4 5
3 4 7 8 2
```

Without the [] and a single integer. I feel like this is what my code should do (excluding bits for if the integer is 0 or 10 where a space should print).
Can anyone give me any insight into why it is printing like this [0, 8, 8, 6]?

I have tried,

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(SimulationArray[i][j]));
```

Using above I get errors. As I suspect I am printing out the sub array rather than printing a single value but I can't understand why or how to solve this.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The relevant parts of your code should be in the question itself, not in a pastebin link ... which is liable to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To print 2D array, you can use nested for-each loop as below:

```
for (int[] x : SimulationArray) {
    for (int y : x) {
        System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loop to print the 2D array.

```
for(int i = 0; i<iLength; i++){
for(int i = 0; i<iLength; i++){
System.out.print(SimulationArray[i][j] +" ");
}
System.out.println("");
}
```